# Invalidate FilePicker URL once S3 upload is complete (without removing s3 file)

Tags: amazon-s3, filepicker.io, filepicker

I am using FilePicker pickAndStore to store to S3. FilePicker stores a permanent reference to file from a publicly accessible URL (Blob.url) and of course one can obtain the file from the s3 key (Blob.key). Is it possible to invalidate FilePicker URL once upload to S3 is complete? That is, after upload, while the S3 Key remains valid but filepicker URL is invalidated so file is never accessible from this publicly-accessible URL?

Answer (score 0):

There is some workaround. You can use FilePicker security:
https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/security/
to prevent from access through FilePicker URL.

Just turn on security on your app and then prepare policy for pick and store add signature and use it with pickAndStore function.